# Round off function in python

Tags: python-3.x

The round function seems pretty tricky in python.
For **round(51.665,2)** it shows **51.66**
and for **round(51.765,2)** it shows **51.77**.
Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: Don't post images use text.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to in binary representation of floating point numbers (numbers in base 10 are sometimes imprecisely represented in base 2). The rationale is more thoroughly described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51840831/6573902) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate/22023918#22023918). More theoretically: [What causes floating point rounding errors?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors)

Important thing to note is that [Python interpreter displays **rounded** floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641678/6573902).

Comment: If the answer helped you please consider accepting it (the gray tick mark besides the up/down vote on the left of the answer).